# The procedure entry point could not be located in dll

Tags: c++, dll, linker, dynamic-linking, dllexport

I have a dll that was working very well without my function! I wrote a function and added it to the dll header file. At first, my function had one parameter and the dll was wroking. Then I decided to add another parameter to my function and then this error appears whenever my function has been called :

```
 The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library.
```

The point is that the added function with one parameter works but when it has two parameters the call fails. Using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), I see that my function exported correctly (_funcName@8). But when I open the main application EXE file using Dependency Walker and explore exported functions in the mentioned dll, it seems that my function doesn't exported correctly (_funcName@4).

The function prototype is as follows :

```
 __declspec(dllexport) int WINAPI funcName(const char *, char *);
```

As you can see, my function has two pointers as parameters, and the number after "@" must be 8 not 4!

I tested the function with and without ***extern "C"***, but nothing changed.I don't know what is the problem??

Comment: Are you using the updated `import library` file when you built your program?  Errors like this occur when you build with a stale `.LIB` file

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie, Yes, I update both `.dll` and `.lib` files after each build.

Comment: Clearly it found a stale copy of the DLL.  How that happened is hard to guess, it is the kind of mishap that occurs when your project's Output Directory isn't configured correctly and you had to copy the DLL by hand.  Delete it.